# Alignment is not in order while I am zooming in and zooming out the web page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[![This is what I am expecting when zoom out or zoom in also.[image: This is what it looks like when I am zooming outThis is what it looks like when zooming in.]

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>ID Card</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index3.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet"     href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-    JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384- DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row d-flex flex-row justify-content-start">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="front">
                        <div class="front-content">
                            <h1 class='name'>Name</h1>
                            <h3 class='designation'>Designation</h3>
                            <h4 class='empId'>EMP ID</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="img-container d-flex flex-row">
                            <img class="image" src="qrcode.jpg" alt="qrcode">
                            <img class="image1" src="sample_image.jpeg" alt="employee_image">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="back content">
                        <h4 class="mr-5" style="font-size:10px">Blood Group</h4>
                        <h5 class="mr-5" style="font-size:10px">O+ve</h5>
                        <h4 class="mr-5" style="font-size:10px">Contact Number</h4>
                        <h5 class="mr-5" style="font-size:10px">9985754321</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
`
```

```
`
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bree+Serif&family=Caveat:wght@400;700&family=Lobster&family=Monoton&family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&family=Playfair+Display+SC:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&family=Source+Sans+Pro:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&family=Work+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&display=swap');
.body{
    text-align: center;
}

.front {
    background-image:url("Sample 1_Potrait Front.png");
    background-size: 20vw 60vh;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:60vh;
    position: relative;
}

.front-content {
   padding:15%;
   margin-right: 25%; 
}
.name {
   color:#1C99AF;
   margin-left: 28%;
   /* margin-top: 20%; */
   font-size: 1.5vw;
   font-weight:bold;     
}

.designation {
    color:#1C3665;
    margin-left: 28%;
    font-size:1vw;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.empId {
    color:#1C3665;
    margin-left: 28%;
    font-size: 0.6vw;
}
.img-container {
    /* padding:10%; */
    margin-top: -2%;
    margin-left:28%;
}

.image {
    height: 6vw;
    width: 6vw;
    /* margin-left: 27%;
    /* margin-top: 7%; */
    /* position: absolute; */ 
}

.image1 {
    height: 9vw;
    width: 9vw;
    margin-left: 9%;
    margin-top: -3%;
    /* margin-bottom: 25%;
     
    /*position: absolute; */
}
.back {
    background-image:url("Sample 1_Potrait Back.png");
    background-size: 20vw 60vh;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:60vh;
    position: relative;

}
.content {
    /* margin-top: 40%; */
    padding:20%;
    margin-right: 12%;
    color:#ffffff;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
}`
```

I have tried multiple ways to giving body text-align to center and giving individual element position to absolute but it won't work when I am zooming out zooming In the webpage. I want same alignment, if we zoom in or zoom out. Those are Id cards front page and back page I have made it statically it's looking good in 100% zoom , but when I decreasing or increasing zoom then my alignment changing drastically. I want the same alignment If I zoom in or zoom out in any device.

Comment: I don't have access to your images, so I can't see how your page looks. Could you provide an image of how your page looks at 100% zoom and how it looks when it's zoomed in or zoomed out?

Comment: I have added images, You can check now.

Comment: The problem is that when you zoom in or zoom out, your viewport size changes, and your  Bootstrap CSS layout depends on viewport size. When the viewport size is small enough, columns with class `col-lg-6` will stretch to fill out the whole width. I haven't used Bootstrap much, but maybe you could solve your problem by changing your classes `col-lg-6` to `col-6`.